# Custom Message with javax.validation.constraints.Future Annotation in Rest Response

Tags: java, rest, bean-validation

I'm trying to present an actual message with a failed validation of an `@Future` Bean Validation annotation but have been unsuccessful thus far.  Here is my current code:

```
public class ForecastDateVO {

@Future(message = "The forecast date must be in the future.")  // Message desired for display
private Date forecastDate;

public Date getForecastDate() {
    return this.forecastDate;
}

public void setForecastDate(final Date forecastDate) {
    this.forecastDate = forecastDate;
    }
}
```

where it is put to use like this:

```
@PUT
@Path("whatever/{projectId}")
public void updateForecastDate(@PathParam("projectId") @NotNull final long projectId,
        @Valid final ForecastDateVO vo) {
      // Something absolutely amazing
}
```

Now the validation is actually working with the `@Valid` tag applied; when I make the rest call with a date in the payload that is **not** in the future I receive a "400 Bad Request".  However, I would like to actually see the error message display in the annotation above.

Is this possible...and if so what's the best way to accomplish it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There is no content with the 400 error response?

Comment: Correct; there is no content.  Just the "Bad Request" message.